# How to associate 2 fields in the same table / data structure?

Tags: database

On my website you can purchase a trip after choosing the departure date (among the available departure dates), knowing that each departure date has a specific price attached to it.

How should I define the [departure date / price] couples from an algorithmic point of view? I suppose they can't simply be 2 fields of the Trip table / data structure, among other fields, because these 2 fields are actually a couple. What then? Should they be contained in a separate table / data structure altogether ?

Just in case I'm working with WordPress on this project.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion should be table DEPARTURE_TERMS, table PRICES and DEPARTURE_PRICES_MAPPER where You have  key ID and pair ID_DEPARTURE_TERMS , ID_PRICES. Now You define all your departures terms with prices and get as

```
SELECT dpm.id, dt.date, pr.price FROM DEPARTURE_PRICES_MAPPER dpm 
JOIN DEPARTURE_TERMS dt ON (dpm.ID_DEPARTURE_TERMS = dt.ID) 
JOIN PRICES pr ON (pr.ID = dpm.id.PRICES)
WHERE dt.date >= '2014-04-12' AND dt.date <= '2014-05-11'
```